# ¿ como pudo validar la informacion del condicional?

Tags: java

quiero validar la informacion de este condicional que cuando ingrese un  numero distinto 2y 1 me envie que el dato esta errado y si ingresa una edad mayor a 110 diga dato errado.

```
int edad,sexo,np ;
Scanner a=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("INGRESE LA EDAD");
edad=a.nextInt();
System.out.println("INGRESE 1 SI ES DE SEXO FEMENINO O 2 SI ES DE SEXO MASCULINO");
sexo=a.nextInt();
if (sexo==1 || sexo==2){
}
if (sexo==1){
    np=(220-edad)/10;
}
 else
 np=(210-edad)/10;
System.out.println("EL NUMERO DE PULSACIONES SON: "  +np );
  }
```

Comment: ¿Y qué no te falta aquí la acción si la o las condiciones se cumplen `if (sexo==1 || sexo==2){
}`?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer las peticiones de ingreso dentro de un `do while` para repetir la petición en caso de un dato incorrecto.

```
int edad, sexo, np;
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("INGRESE LA EDAD");
        edad = a.nextInt();

        if (edad >= 100) {
            System.out.println("Dato erróneo");
        }

    } while (edad >= 110);

    do {
        System.out.println("INGRESE 1 SI ES DE SEXO FEMENINO O 2 SI ES DE SEXO MASCULINO");
        sexo = a.nextInt();

        if (sexo < 1 || sexo > 2) {
            System.out.println("Dato erróneo");
        }

    } while (sexo < 1 || sexo > 2);


    if (sexo == 1) {
        np = (220 - edad) / 10;
    } else
        np = (210 - edad) / 10;


System.out.println("EL NUMERO DE PULSACIONES SON: " + np);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool hayError = false;
string mensajeError = "Se detectaron los siguientes errores:\n\n";

if(sexo > 2 || sexo < 1)
{
    mensajeError += "Sexo no válido\n";
    hayError = true;
}

if(edad > 110)
{
    mensajeError += "Edad no válida\n";
    hayError = true;
}

if(hayError)
{          
    System.out.println(mensajeError);
}
else
{
    np = (sexo == 1) ?
         (220 - edad)/10 :
         (210 -   edad)/10;
}
```

Lo primero que se hace aquí es validar que no haya ningún dato erróneo, para ello utilizo la **variable booleana hayError** la cual será **true** si hay algún error, y la **variable mensajeError** que irá concatenando los mensajes de error. Posteriormente se pregunta si la **variable hayError** es **true**, en caso de serlo se imprime el mensaje de error, en caso de no serlo se hace el cálculo atendiendo el sexo de la persona, para hallar este cálculo se usa el **operador ternario ?:** el cual funciona como:

```
if()
{
}
else
{
}
```